# Count/Sum Values in a table with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I am trying to return a count of "Yes" in a column of a table based on another criteria (i.e. "Sprint"), as well as the sum of another column's values based on the "Yes" criteria and the "Sprint" (So, two formulas but very similar. One just goes a little further). Here's a dumbed down example of my table below:

[image]

I would like to count the amount of stories are late ("Yes") in the late column for a specific sprint. So, I know there should be 2 that were late in sprint 1, and one in sprint 2...

Additionally, I would also like to get the sum of effort for these late items. So, for sprint 1, it should be "6" and for sprint 2 it should be "1".

Does anyone know if this is possible? I looked at COUNTIF and SUMIF and those don't appear to go the extra portion of only counting values given a specific criteria (i.e. a sprint number) and I don't think a VLOOKUP would be needed since I know the values. I'm kind of at a loss...

Thank you.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) and [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Basically did > SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,[@Sprint],E:E,"Yes",C:C,"User Story") since i had some for bugs and other items. That gave me the correct numbers. The Count was easier, just remove the first "D:D" and the rest stays.